# How to write post-checkout hook to chmod 666 to all files?

Tags: git

```
##!/bin/bash
## post-chekcout script
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 666
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```

Above is my `post-chekcout` hook, I want to :
After `git checkout`,change all files in my working directory to mod `666` and change all folders to `777`.

But in [this post](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout),

> This hook cannot affect the outcome of git checkout

How can I write post-checkout hook to `chmod 666` to all files?

Comment: Giving the world write access to your files is extremely poor security practice. I hope you have thought this through.

Comment: @tripleee,IDE like `netbean` need write access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> This hook cannot affect the outcome of git checkout

means that exit code of the hook cannot prevent checkout being performed. The hook is ran after checkout and you can do anything in the worktree. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
# post-checkout hook:
# chmod directories and executable files 0777,
# chmod other files 0666. Exclude .git.
find . \( -name .git -type d -prune \) -o -exec chmod a+rwX '{}' \+
```

Comment: simple and solid answer!

Comment: But this will cause `.git` changed.How to avoid it?

Comment: This is a little bit more complex but possible with `find`. Update the answer.