# How to make `git lfs` recognize `core.filemode=false`?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I use `git-lfs 2.4.2` with `git 1.8.3.1` in centos 7. 
git config as below:

```
[root@localhost www]# git config --list
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
core.safecrlf=true
core.filemode=false
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.safecrlf=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Through [How to write post-checkout hook to chmod 666 to all files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071612/how-to-write-post-checkout-hook-to-chmod-666-to-all-files)  ,I set `post-checkout` hook as below:

```
##!/bin/bash
## post-chekcout script

set -e

command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs post-checkout "$@"

exec chmod -R a+rwX .
```

After `git checkout -b develop`, a lots of `.jpg`,`.gif` (files tracked by git-lfs) chagned mod as below:

```
# On branch develop
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   modified:   admin/images/admin_tit_bg.jpg
#   modified:   user/images/ajax_loader.gif
```

After that,I run `git commit -am`,then `git checkout master`,get below errors:

```
Pointer file error: Unable to parse pointer at: "admin/images/admin_tit_bg.jpg"
Pointer file error: Unable to parse pointer at: "user/images/ajax_loader.gif"
Checking out files: 100% (321/321), done.
Switched to branch 'master'
```

It seemed `git-lfs` doesn't recognize `core.filemode=false`.How to solve it?